# Difference between `apply_gradients` and `minimize` of optimizer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am confused about the difference between `apply_gradients` and `minimize` of optimizer in tensorflow. For example,

```py
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cnn.loss)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)
```

and

```py
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(cnn.loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Are they the same indeed?

If I want to decay the learning rate, can I use the following codes?

```py
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
starter_learning_rate = 1e-3
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step,
                                       100, FLAGS.decay_rate, staircase=True)
# Passing global_step to minimize() will increment it at each step.
learning_step = (
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cnn.loss)
    train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can easily know from the link : https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started
(tf.train API part) that they actually do the same job.
The difference it that: if you use the separated functions( tf.gradients, tf.apply_gradients), you can apply other mechanism between them, such as gradient clipping.

Comment: A link on the docs where this is explained better is https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer .

Comment: I am afraid that neither of those links seem to explain the situation fully to me. For instance "minimize" seems to be doing something with the gradient tape automatically, whilst you have to do this manually with apply_gradients or something?

Comment: links are both outdated.. do you have updated versions somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

[here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#minimize) it says `minimize` uses `tf.GradienTape` and then `apply_gradients`:

> Minimize loss by updating var_list.
>
> This method simply computes gradient using tf.GradientTape and calls
> apply_gradients(). If you want to process the gradient before applying
> then call tf.GradientTape and apply_gradients() explicitly instead of
> using this function.

So `minimize` actually uses `apply_gradients` just like:

```
def minimize(self, loss, var_list, grad_loss=None, name=None, tape=None):
    grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(loss, var_list=var_list, grad_loss=grad_loss, tape=tape)
    return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
```

---

In your example, you use `compute_gradients` and `apply_gradients`, this is indeed valid but nowadays, `compute_gradients` was made private and is therefore not good practice to use it. For this reason the function is not longer on the documentation.